# Animating tap gesture in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make my app more beautiful, so I was wondering how to make tap animation.
Something like "Cut the rope" swipe cut or tapping in "Path" app. I want to show blink under my finger when I'm tapping. Is it possible or will take a lot of work?
I can't find such example. Maybe someone knows how to do that.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at [touchesMoved](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:). You have to subclass UIView and overwrite this method. I will not give a complete answer because this would feel as if others do the job of googling for you - maybe you can answer your own question with these hints.

Comment: I tried searching but everything is about animathing things after tapping. Of course I can watch gesture, then remember coordinates and make there view with animation or something like that, but I fought that maybe there is some simple way I can't find. I'm quite new in objective-c. Thanks for link and your time :)